# echoing a item from an array in php

Tags: php

I have this:

```
array(1) {
        ["summoners"]=> array(1) {
              [0]=> array(2) { 
                  ["id"]=> int(49006104) ["name"]=> string(5) "Śký" 
              }  
        }
}
```

I wondered how I would go about using echo to show the name of the character (Śký)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [RTM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
echo $your_array['summoners'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$arr['summoners'][0]['name']`?

Comment: It returns null :/ I'm using `$decode_name = json_decode($find_name, true);` to create the array

Comment: @FDL submit an answer and I'll set you as answer, ty.

Comment: Can you show the json data? Did you change the `$your_array` to `$decode_name`?

Comment: @user3352340 That's for *decoding*, that's considering `$find_name` is an JSON String.

Comment: @user3352340 just accept this one, it's now correct.